# how to send params in react.js using useNavigate in react-router-dom version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";
import Detailpost from "../../DetailPost/detailpost";

const Post = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="post">
            <div className="img-thum">
                <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/tech" alt="IMG" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <div
                  className="title"
                  onClick={()=>props.Detail(props.data.id)}
                >
                  {props.data.title}
                </div>
                <div className="Body">{props.data.body}</div>
                <div className="rem">
                <button
                  className="remove"
                  onClick={() => props.remove(props.data.id)}
                >
                  Remove
                </button>  
                <button
                  className="update"
                  onClick={() => props.update(props.data)}
                >
                  Update
                </button>  
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

In this case I'll make when I click the title I move to another page.

```
handleDetail = (id) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate('/detail-post', { UserId: id })
}
```

but when I run the code I get some problem:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component.

anyone can help me..

Answer (score 3):

## Issues

1. You are breaking the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) by conditionally call the `useNavigate` hook.

   > ### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
   >
   > Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or ***nested functions***. Instead, always use Hooks at the top
   > level of your React function, before any early returns. By following
   > this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each
   > time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly
   > preserve the state of Hooks between multiple `useState` and `useEffect`
   > calls.
2. You are not passing the state correctly. The `navigate` function takes a second argument options object with `state` and `replace` keys. Any data you want to send along with the route transition should be on the `state` key.

   [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

   > ```
   > declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
   >
   > interface NavigateFunction {
   >   (
   >     to: To,
   >     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
   >   ): void;
   >   (delta: number): void;
   > }
   > ```

## Solution

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

handleDetail = (UserId) => {
  navigate('/detail-post', { state: { UserId } });
}

...
```

And OFC use the `useLocation` hook on the receiving route to access the passed route state.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { state } = useLocation();
const { UserId } = state || {};

...
```

Answer (score 0):

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) is a hook, and as [a rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level), only call hooks at the top level of your React component

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleDetail = (id) => {
    navigate('/detail-post', {UserId:id})
  }

  // ...
}
```